# ggplot to R - dataframe R

Tags: python, r, django, ggplot2

We are trying to convert our application that builds on shiny to Django . We have our custom library for analytics written in R and we have integrated it in our Django using rpy2 library. Now this is the situation, Our library returns ggplot2 instance for plotting graphs. We can't change that library and have to use it for analytics purpose. So what we want is to convert that ggplot2 instance into R - data frame so then we can convert it in Json and sent to our front end to plot graphs. So is there a way to do this . Is it somehow possible to convert ggplot2 instance to data frame in R ?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question... You can access the data in a ggplot object by using `ObjectName$data`.  If you want to parse the whole ggplot object to json that should be doable as well, but there should not be a need to convert it to a data frame first.

Comment: so can you please tell me how to do it ... I am very much beginner in R

Comment: You want the whole object to be a json array?  What are you going to do with it?  I don't see how that will help you? Does your front end take ggplot objects in json?

Comment: actually .. our data science team made a library in R for analytics purpose and made a web app using it's Shiny server ... now we are aiming for an enterprise solution that involves that custom library . Our custom library return ggplot2 instance for plotting some graph. So i need to convert that into json to so that i can make an API using DRF(Django Rest Framework) to display graphs at our front-end

Comment: so yeah i want the whole object of ggplot2 data on which graph is plotted into JSON

Comment: What do you have on your front end that will turn the ggplot object into a graph?  Much of a plot object is R function references.

Comment: One other option would be to use the plumber package.  To set up an api on an R server to return completed graph images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177378/discussion-between-ian-wesley-and-osama).